# Basic authentication from database

Tags: rest, jersey, basic-authentication

I have developed a `Rest API` using Jersey for my Java application and also implemented basic authentication. Is it possible to authenticate a user from the database instead of authenticating them through the `Web.xml` file?

Comment: yes, create servlet, pass usern/pass from login page to servlet and authenticate, that's what most of webapp do

Comment: I can login to my web application through login page by verifying the user through DB, but i want to verify RestAPI URI through DB.

Comment: your db should support that feature ... most of relational db only can be connected via jdbc, try couchDb, it works on REST as well.